# Rails-7 ArgumentError Unknown key: :on. Valid keys are: :if, :unless, :prepend | mongoid-paperclip

Tags: rubygems, mongoid, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-7

I am a beginner I am trying to migrate Rails 4 to rails 7.0.6 for upload image i used
mongoid-paperclip

```rb
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid.git', branch: 'master'
gem 'mongoid-paperclip', require: 'mongoid_paperclip'
```

IN Model

```rb
has_mongoid_attached_file :image,
                            :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/images/:organization_id/meals/:id/:style.:extension",
                            :url => "/uploads/meals/:id/:style.:extension",
                            :styles => {
                                :small => ['100x100', :png],
                                :app_show_display  => ['768x431#', :png],
                            }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"], :message => "You should select the right format"
  can_attach_from_remote_url :image
```

after updating with the if conditions, still i am facing the issue .

```rb
has_mongoid_attached_file :image,
                            :if => :attach_file_condition
                            :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/images/:organization_id/meals/:id/:style.:extension",
                            :url => "/uploads/meals/:id/:style.:extension",
                            :styles => {
                                :small => ['100x100', :png],
                                :app_show_display  => ['768x431#', :png],
                            }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"], :message => "You should select the right format"
  can_attach_from_remote_url :image

def attach_file_condition
    if !org.id.nil?
        true
      else
        false
      end
  end
```

Comment: For me, the only thing that fixed this was downgrading my project.  For me, I had to downgrade from 7.1.1 to 7.0.6, so maybe your version would work with a clean bundle on 7.0.6 now, given that some of the other dependencies may be upgraded/fixed in that version for you.

Comment: Actually.. found the issue here, and the workaround works with latest Rails 7 and mongoid versions. The issue is in kt-paperclip - in lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb line 97 sets an unsupported :on condition for :after_commit. If you can avoid using after_commit, you should be fine. You'll of course need to fork kt-paperclip though.

Comment: Same problème, and thats what I've done, thanks @WedgeMartin